# How can I increase the size of the icons in applications overview as well as spacing between them( Gnome 20.4 LTS)?

Tags: gnome-shell

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?

This is how the icons appear here
[image: This is how the icons appear here]

Comment: What version of GNOME are you using?