# How to increase size of application icon size in Show application menu?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, dock

When I place `gnome-dock` to right/left, icons of `Show Application` appears to be bigger. But I like dock at the bottom as when-ever I tried to scroll page, dock appears and open some applications.
[The icon size I want when dock at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxLN5.jpg)
vs
[The size I get when dock at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COsdD.jpg)

Comment: A similar question remained unanswered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354619/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-the-icons-in-applications-overview-as-well-as-spa I am afraid this will involve editing source code. Yet another one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306368/inside-the-app-section-is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-the-icons-in-ubuntu